# AWS Cognito - Change sign in attributes after pool is created

Tags: amazon-cognito

Is it possible to change the sign-in attributes to allow sign-in with email besides user name after the pool is created? Right now the option is disabled, and I can't figure out how to change it.

Also allow sign in with verified email address

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a issue that never got fixed:

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/1546